# BPMN Unit test failing in Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, camunda, bpmn, zeebe

For the BPMN, I have written the unit test cases. It's working for the positive scenario but failing for the negative scenario. Below is the error. Please post your inputs. When it's executing the below line its giving the error. completeServiceTask(CANCEL_WORKFLOW, false);

```
{
client.newDeployResourceCommand()
        .addResourceFromClasspath("xyz.bpmn")
        .send()
        .join();

String Id = "ABC";

Model model= new Model();
model.setId("ABC");

ZeebeWorkflow zeebeWorkflow = new ZeebeWorkflow(Id, model);

PublishMessageResponse messageResponse = sendMessage(START_WORKFLOW,Id, zeebeWorkflow);
completeServiceTask(VALIDATION, false);
sendMessage(BOOK_WORKFLOW, Id, new BookMessagePayload("user","app"));
completeServiceTask(PROCESS_BOOKING, false);
sendMessage(CANCEL_WORKFLOW_MESSAGE, Id, new ZeebeMessagePayload());
completeServiceTask(CANCEL_WORKFLOW, false);
BpmnAssert.assertThat(messageResponse)
        .hasCreatedProcessInstance()
        .extractingProcessInstance()
        .hasPassedElementsInOrder(VALIDATION,PROCESS_BOOKING,CANCEL_WORKFLOW)
        .hasVariableWithValue("Id", "ABC")
        .hasVariableWithValue("user", "user")
        .isCompleted();
}
```

Below is the Error message

> org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Unable to activate 1 jobs, because only 0 were activated.

Comment: Your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77872517/bpmn-unit-test-failing-in-java) was closed as lacking an [mcve]. This one appears to be identical. Are you sure you have enough code to reproduce the issue here?

Comment: TylerH : yes it has enough code to reproduce the issue.